# JS Function Calls from HTML + Reactive display

Tags: javascript, html, button

The game is WAR, or Get Your Neighbour, a traditional game utilising a standard deck of 52 cards, no jokers. Currently the code recognises when a card is above 10 and so the rules of the game are being followed, all that is great, I've designed a timer that takes the value of the card 2-14, subtracts 10, then uses that number for the round of turns the other player has to draw above 10 before you win. Still building the cooperative/multiplayer element but for now, I'd just like to get this bloody button working!

When I click it, it does nothing. Before, it would tell me that "'timerf' is not a function". I'm probably doing something very obvious like problems with the order that things are loaded/data is parsed, but I'm still learning so I'd appreciate any help! Any questions, let me know.

```js
var card = null; // setem 160517
var timer = null; //
    
window.onload = function() {
   function draw(min, max) { // draw a card between 2-14
      card = document.getElementById("draw").innerHTML = Math.floor(Math.random()*((max - min)+1) + min); // min 2, max 14
       if (card > 10) {
        timer = card - 10;
        timerf(timer);
       } else if (card < 11 && timer > 0) {
        timer = timerf(timer-1);
       }
    } // draw
   //draw(2,14);
  document.getElementById("clickMe").onclick = draw(2,14);
 } // window.onload
    
function timerf(timer) { // print turns to win
    if (timer > 0 && timer < 5 && timer != 1) { // print turns to win
      console.log("you have " + timer + " turns to win!");
    } else if (timer == 1) {
      console.log("you have " + timer + " turn to win!");
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="draw"></div>
<button id="clickMe">WAR!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The return value of the `draw` function is `undefined` because it has no `return` statement.

> ```
> document.getElementById("clickMe").onclick = draw(2,14);
> ```

… so you are assigning `undefined` to the `onclick` property.

You have to assign the function you want to call.

Comment: Thanks, you're right - I omitted return early because I was using console.log. I added a "return card;" line in the function, but still nothing - same as before, no result when I press the button (not even an error in the console)

Comment: @SamiEtem — `card = document.getElementById("draw").innerHTML` — That's a string. You have to assign the **function** you want to call.

Comment: So 'card' becomes the string displayed in the div 'draw' - which is generated from the math.random func. You're saying I need to assign the function Draw(); to card? So card = draw(2,14); or something like that? - edit: yeah I obviously don't want the return to be the function that contains it, that's just stupid. I'm totally burnt out so I should come back to this!

Comment: @SamiEtem — The card variable is irrelevant. You need to assign a function to `onclick`

Comment: Thanks. I thought I had though?  `document.getElementById("clickMe").onclick = draw(2,14);`

Comment: Sorry, just saw you meant the earlier card = document.get etc. I'll take a look and get back when I've worked it all out!

Comment: @SamiEtem — `draw` is a function, `draw(2,14)` is the return value of calling that function … which is `undefined`.